# How to draw a horizontal plot with TiKz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

can anyone help me to understand how to draw this shape with `tikz`? also, can you send me the main reference of this concept in `www.tikz.dev`?
[image]

Comment: Welcome. Start with the [tutorials](https://tikz.dev/tutorial). I see one [straight line](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#pgf.--) with [arrow tips](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows), a bunch of ticks (→ straight lines) with numbers below them (→ [nodes](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes)), seems like a case for [`\foreach`](https://tikz.dev/pgffor). The curves are best done by [`to[out=<angle A>, in=<angle B>]` or `bend left`/`bend right` even](https://tikz.dev/library-edges#sec-74.3).

Comment: What's www.tikz.dev? And why do you think it has this diagram?

Comment: Please feel free to re-open your question if the linked answer does not help.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Dear friend, you really helped me to find the solution of this problem. Thank you so much!